# Drupal 7 - change textfield values depending on select value

Tags: forms, drupal

I have two drupal forms on one page and I do not understand how the ajax callback works in order to change values of one form based on value of the first form.

My forms:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['first_form'] = [
        '#title' => t('Choose:') ,
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => [
            '1' => 'First',
            '2' => 'Second',
            '3' => 'Third',
        ],
        '#required' => '1',
        '#ajax' => [
            'method' => 'replace',
            'callback' => 'my_form_state_ajax_callback',
        ],
    ];

    //---------------------

    $form['second_form'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => "Second form",
    ];

    $form['second_form']['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#title' => 'Name.',
    ];

    $form['second_form']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Go",
        '#submit' => ['my_form_submit'],
    ];
}
```

The callback function:

```
function my_form_state_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

    switch ($form_state['values']['id']) {
        case 1:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'One';
            break;
        case 2:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'Two';
            break;
        case 3:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'Three';
            break;
    }

    return $form['edit_medal'];
}
```

Basically, if I choose `First` in the select dropdown, I want to change the second's form `name` field to `One` etc. If I don't select anything in the select dropdown, values of the second form's fields won't be set.

The above code does not work though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to put both forms in one? Just asking. (I wouldn't expect that what you are trying will work across forms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this first_form you have to add `'wrapper'` and `'prefix', 'suffix'` like

```
     function my_form($form, &$form_state) {

            $form['first_form'] = [
                '#title' => t('Choose:') ,
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#options' => [
                    '1' => 'First',
                    '2' => 'Second',
                    '3' => 'Third',
                ],
                '#required' => '1',
                '#ajax' => [
                    'method' => 'replace',
                    'callback' => 'my_form_state_ajax_callback',
                    'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div'
                ],
            ];
            $form['second_form']['name'] = [
                 '#type' => 'textfield',
                 '#required' => TRUE,
                 '#title' => 'Name.',
                 '#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxes-div">',
                 '#suffix' => '</div>',
            ];
    }
```

in callback function you have to return that field which you want to update like `$form['second_form']['name']`

```
function my_form_state_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

    switch ($form_state['values']['first_form']) {
        case 1:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'One';
            break;
        case 2:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'Two';
            break;
        case 3:
            $form['second_form']['name']['#value'] = 'Three';
            break;
    }

    return $form['second_form']['name'];
}
```